# Why is this SQL convert to bigint not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inner joining a few SQL Server tables, and there is a `varchar` column that needs to match up with a numeric column. I am attempting to convert that column to `bigint`, but it will come up with

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

when attempting to do so. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    userid, COUNT(DISTINCT maintlist.maintid) as thecount 
FROM 
    Userlist 
INNER JOIN 
    maintlist ON CONVERT(bigint, MaintList.enteredby) = userid 
INNER JOIN
    maintnotes ON maintnotes.maintid = maintlist.maintid 
WHERE
    deptnum <> '0' 
    AND notedate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '11/1/2015' 
GROUP BY 
    userid 
ORDER BY  
    thecount DESC;
```

Comment: There must a record in your table that can't be converted to `BIGINT`.

Comment: You need to dig through your data and check it. You'll find that it will be something like 'A' - you can't convert that to a number. You can convert your int to a varchar though. Of course you'll never match anything to 'A' and '001' <> '1'

Comment: Is `userid` of type BIGINT? are all values in `enteredby` field numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some user IDs in the maintlist table can't be converted from varchar to bigint, converting the user ID in the userlist table to varchar means that your code will work, but your join will not give the results you want. So I'd still go looking for the user IDs that can't be converted.

Comment: This answer led me in the right direction, and I ended up joining the tables differently which resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I was able to convert the userid to varchar instead.

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(DISTINCT maintlist.maintid) as thecount from Userlist inner join maintlist ON MaintList.enteredby = convert(varchar(20),userid) inner join maintnotes on maintnotes.maintid = maintlist.maintid where deptnum <> '0' AND notedate between '2015-10-01' AND '11/1/2015' group by userid order by thecount DESC;
```